# Armadillo linking error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, armadillo

I am currently trying to compile a simple C++ test program using [optim](https://github.com/kthohr/optim).

This library uses [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) and I keep getting the following error message

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "*ddot*", referenced
>   from:
>         double arma::blas::dot(unsigned long long, double const*, double const*) in main.cpp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

My program code looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include "optim.hpp"

double sphere_fn(const arma::vec& vals_inp, arma::vec* grad_out, void* opt_data)
{
    double obj_val = arma::dot(vals_inp,vals_inp);
    //
    if (grad_out) {
        *grad_out = 2.0*vals_inp;
    }
    //
    return obj_val;
}

double booth_fn(const arma::vec& vals_inp, arma::vec* grad_out, void* opt_data)
{
    double x_1 = vals_inp(0);
    double x_2 = vals_inp(1);

    double obj_val = std::pow(x_1 + 2*x_2 - 7.0,2) + std::pow(2*x_1 + x_2 - 5.0,2);
    //
    if (grad_out) {
        (*grad_out)(0) = 2*(x_1 + 2*x_2 - 7.0) + 2*(2*x_1 + x_2 - 5.0)*2;
        (*grad_out)(1) = 2*(x_1 + 2*x_2 - 7.0)*2 + 2*(2*x_1 + x_2 - 5.0);
    }
    //
    return obj_val;
}

int main()
{
    //
    // sphere function

    const int test_dim = 5;

    arma::vec x = arma::ones(test_dim,1); // initial values (1,1,...,1)

    bool success = optim::lbfgs(x,sphere_fn,nullptr);

    if (success) {
        std::cout << "lbfgs: sphere test completed successfully." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "lbfgs: sphere test completed unsuccessfully." << std::endl;
    }

    arma::cout << "lbfgs: solution to sphere test:\n" << x << arma::endl;

    //
    // Booth function

    arma::vec x_2 = arma::zeros(2,1); // initial values (0,0)

    bool success_2 = optim::lbfgs(x,booth_fn,nullptr);

    if (success_2) {
        std::cout << "lbfgs: Booth test completed successfully." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "lbfgs: Booth test completed unsuccessfully." << std::endl;
    }

    arma::cout << "lbfgs: solution to Booth test:\n" << x_2 << arma::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Similar questions have been asked over and over again in this forum. I read so many threads and I still can't figure out how to solve this problem.

People say it would help linking with -larmadillo. For some reason this does not work me. So here is my CMAKE script

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TESTPROJECT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Accelerate")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

find_package( ARMADILLO REQUIRED )

add_executable(TESTPROJECT ${SOURCE_FILES})

link_directories(... /usr/local/lib)
include_directories(... ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR} /usr/include /usr/local/include/optim)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  ${GCC_ARMADILLO_LINK_FLAG}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_ARMADILLO_LINK_FLAG}")

target_link_libraries(TESTPROJECT ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} optim)
```

Running make after cmake results in the error above on my macOS. However, if I uncomment set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Accelerate"), it does work. But then the I get incorrect results for the above test functions.

I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: `ddot` is from BLAS, so link with BLAS or the much better OpenBLAS.  The latter is faster. Link with LAPACK while you are it it.  Example: `g++ code.cpp -o code -O2 -lopenblas -llapack`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Compiling the code like this results in the same behaviour as uncommenting -framework Accelerate.